# How to find matching braces in string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looping through a templated dictionary doing substitutions.  The values in the dictionary look like this:

```
foo{sub1}{sub2}bar{sub3}
```

where `foo`, `bar`, and `subN` can be any random text (not containing a brace character).

I'm trying to identify `{sub1}`, `{sub2}`, and `{sub3}` in the list.  I can parse the characters myself but assume there is a 1-liner solution.

Anybody see it?

Comment: You're going to have problems if ever your braces can be nested or a part of the random text.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. Luckily that can't happen here.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> re.findall('{.*?}', 'foo{sub1}{sub2}bar{sub3}')
['{sub1}', '{sub2}', '{sub3}']
```

[findall](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.findall) finds... all occurrences of the pattern and returns a list. Use [finditer](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.finditer) if you want an iterator.

Note, though, that if your string contains stuff like `{abc{def}}`, the pattern won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
>>> s = 'foo{sub1}{sub2}bar{sub3}'
>>> re.findall('{([^}]+)}', s)
['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']
```

We capture everything that's inside `{` and `}`, then `findall` simply returns a list with all matched groups.

If you want to keep the `{` and `}` as part of the matched strings, simply remove the group:

```
re.findall('{[^}]+}', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

regex solution is two-line solution, because you must import module before. :)
There is a simple tricky solution with list generation and split method:

```
>>> [x.split('}')[0] for x in 'foo{sub1}{sub2}bar{sub3}'.split('{') if '}' in x]
['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub3']
```

Comment: Ha! No, strictly one line isn't necessary.  ;)  Thanks for the submission!